# How can i implement a factory pattern with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, factory-pattern

I need to implement a function called 'learn skill'. In the controller i added this code:

```
public function learnskill( $character_id, $skillname )
{
    $this->load->model('skillfactory_model');
    // Ideally i would need that the factory returns the model
    // skill_parry_model so i can use it
    $skill_instance = $this->skill_factory_model->create($skillname);
    $skill_instance->learn($character_id);
 }
```

How can i implement the model 'skill_factory_model' and how i can write the controller and follow CI guidelines?

Answer (score 0):

Found out a way to do it:

```
public function learnskill( $character_id, $skillname )
{  

    $this->load->model('skillfactory_model');
    $model = $this->skillfactory_model->create($skillname]);
    $this->load->model($model);
    $this->$model->learn($character_id);
}
```

SkillFactory_Model:

```
class SkillFactory_Model extends CI_Model
{

    public function create($tag)
    {   
        $class = "Skill_" . $tag . '_model';                        
        return $class;
    }

}
```